# Problem with custom Authentication Backend for Django

Tags: django, authentication, ldap

I'm having a problem with a custom Authentication Backend I've built for an Active Directory via LDAP authentication.

The problem is that from the admin login page, after it properly authenticates and creates the new user in the database (or updates their info from the LDAP server), but then returns me to the admin login page indicating that I failed to enter a valid username and password.

Considering it authenticates and creates/updates the user in the django database, what am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
import ldap
import re
from django.conf import ad_settings
grps = re.compile(r'CN=(\w+)').findall

def anyof(short_group_list, adu):
    all_groups_of_user = set(g for gs in adu.get('memberOf',()) for g in grps(gs))
    return any(g for g in short_group_list if g in all_groups_of_user)

class ActiveDirectoryBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    This backend utilizes an ActiveDirectory server via LDAP to authenticate
    users, creating them in Django if they don't already exist.
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        con = None
        ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
        try:
            con = ldap.initialize('ldap://%s:%s' % (ad_settings.AD_DNS_NAME,
                  ad_settings.AD_LDAP_PORT))
            con.simple_bind_s(username+"@"+ad_settings.AD_DNS_NAME, password)
            ADUser = con.search_ext_s(ad_settings.AD_SEARCH_DN,
                                      ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                      "sAMAccountName=%s" % username,
                                      ad_settings.AD_SEARCH_FIELDS)[0][1]
            con.unbind()
        except ldap.LDAPError:
            return None
        # Does user belong to appropriate AD group?
        if not anyof(ad_settings.PROJECTCODE,ADUser):
            return None

        # Does user already exist in Django?
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            #create Django user
            user = User(username=username, is_staff = True, is_superuser = False)
        #Update User info from AD
        if ADUser.has_key('givenName'):
            user.first_name = ADUser.get('givenName')[0]
        if ADUser.has_key('sn'):
            user.last_name = ADUser.get('sn')[0]
        if ADUser.has_key('mail'):
            user.email = ADUser.get('mail')[0]

        # Does not store password in Django.
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()
        return user
```

EDIT: Figured out.  Users cannot log in unless they are active (even though the documentation does not say that).  Therefore, in the code given, the line that creates the new user should look like:

```
        user = User(username=username, is_staff = True, is_Active = True, 
                    is_superuser = False)
```

Comment: I was looking for this, because I need to write similar stuff. Thanks for posting this :-)

Comment: Have you considered using mod_ldap and the RemoteUserMiddleware?

Comment: You should put your edit in a question and mark it as the answer so this question becomes 'answered'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out. Users cannot log in unless they are active (even though the documentation does not say that). Therefore, in the code given, the line that creates the new user should look like:

```
    user = User(username=username, is_staff = True, is_Active = True, 
                is_superuser = False)
```