# Going about Implementing Authentication/Authorization using CouchDb as backend in Django

Tags: django, couchdb

I need to store both authentication and authorization information in couchdb. I've used a similar method to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105312/problem-with-custom-authentication-backend-for-django) for implementing authentication. However, what do I need to implement authorization for users. I need that certain actions be called only by specific users. Will using the user_passes_test decorator be a good idea for this?

I am also looking to move the session store to a separate couchdb instance. Will this be a good idea? Can anyone give me pointers/examples on how to go about this.

I am new to both Python and Django.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, all you need to implement is the "authenticate" method of your custom authentication backend.  The [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) have some decent examples of how you could implement an authentication backend.

In regard to your permissions question, it depends on the exact details of what types of permission checks you need.  If your permissions model fits well with Django's existing permissions system, you can make make authorizations decisions based on data in couchdb by implementing the optional permission bits in your custom authentication backend. Again, the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) have details on how exactly to do this.

As far as the session store, I don't know enough about CouchDB's performance characteristics to say if you need to store session data in a separate instance or not.  What I can tell you however is either way, the way you use a CouchDB instance as your session store is to use a custom [session engine](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/sessions/).  With a quick look around, it looks like [django-couchdb-utils](https://github.com/theju/django-couchdb-utils) can provide you with a session engine that you could drop in without too much work (might also have some other useful bits for you).